# repmgr 4.4 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I did `apt-get install repmgr` and tried to upgrade repmgr from 4.3 to 4.4

```
root@node-01:~# apt-get install repmgr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  repmgr
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 251 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,324 B of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://dl.2ndquadrant.com/default/release/apt xenial-2ndquadrant/main amd64 repmgr all 4.4-1.xenial+1 [5,324 B]
Fetched 5,324 B in 0s (5,495 B/s)
Selecting previously unselected package repmgr.
(Reading database ... 65744 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../repmgr_4.4-1.xenial+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking repmgr (4.4-1.xenial+1) ...
Setting up repmgr (4.4-1.xenial+1) ...
```

However, `repmgr --version` still shows version 4.3.

```
postgres@node-01:~$ repmgr --version
repmgr 4.3
```

Did I miss some steps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: type `which repmgr` and be sure that the path is correct

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install postgresql-10-repmgr` fixed the issue.